# Оценка сложности пароля

Tags: c++builder, дизайн

Нужно в графическом виде предоставлять пользователю оценку сложности генерированного пароля. Как это можно реализовать в C++ Bulider? Нужен не алгоритм а варианты как именно в ГРАФИЧЕСКОМ виде предоставлять пользователю оценку сложности генерированного пароля.

**Для анализа стойкости используются следующие показатели:**

*Длина пароля*

*Количество используемых типов символов: заглавные латинские, малые латинские, цифры, спец-символы*

**Стойкость пароля подразделяется на пять классов**

**Отличный (Best) —**

*Длина пароля — не менее 14.
Количество используемых различных типов символов — не менее 3.*

**Стойкий (Strong) —**

*Длина пароля — не менее 8.
Количество используемых различных типов символов — не менее 3.*

**Средний (Medium) —**

*Длина пароля — не менее 8.
Количество используемых различных типов символов — не менее 2.*

**Слабый (Weak) —**

*Пароль состоит как минимум из одного произвольного символа.*

**Никакой —**

*Все остальные пароли.*

Comment: Цветом: от красного через желтый к зеленому.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Посмотрите показатели которые я добавил в пост

Comment: Это не меняет ровным словом ничего. Ваш вопрос "как именно в ГРАФИЧЕСКОМ виде..." вот я и говорю: цветом, в зависимости от вышеприведенных классов.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Подскажете компонент в котором можно так сделать? ProgressBar?

Comment: Например можно поле ввода использовать: менять цвет текста/фона.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Это вся графика? Этот вариант очень слаб...

Comment: Вам на сайт дизайнеров/художников.

Comment: @Евгений а давайте вы сами посмотрите какая у вас там графика доступна?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Графики есть